# Download Facebook Messenger thread (on Mac)

Tags: facebook-messenger

I would like to download a very long Facebook Messenger thread to my computer for safekeeping (I’m on Mac if it makes any difference). Any way to do this easily?

I’m no computer wiz.

Answer (score 1):

Ask for an archive from Facebook via your personal settings (Download a copy of your Facebook data.). This is the simplest way.

Any further needs programming and is beyond the scope of Web Apps.